# How can I avoid unnecessary loading of Associated model while creating it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

In my Rails app, we have a couple of models similar to this

```rb
class Pen < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ink
  after_create :add_ink

  def add_ink
    create_ink(color: "blue")
  end
end

class Ink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pen
end
```

and in a Controller we do something like this

```rb
pen = Pen.new(..)
pen.save
```

Conceptually, a Pen always has an Ink, and we create the Ink when the Pen is created. (Also open to better ways to accomplish this than an after_create hook).

The problem is that it's always issuing a SELECT for the association even though there's guaranteed to be nothing there.

```
[DEBUG]   TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
[DEBUG]   Pen Create (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO pens ("owner_id") VALUES ('00f74077-c079-4482-aa03-15b23951a7bd') RETURNING "id"
[DEBUG]   Ink Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "inks".* FROM "inks" WHERE "inks"."pen_id" = '93a45bae-2cf3-48c1-ac00-6b3059dca5ae' LIMIT 1
[DEBUG]   Ink Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "inks" ("pen_id", "color") VALUES ('93a45bae-2cf3-48c1-ac00-6b3059dca5ae', 'blue') RETURNING "pen_id"
[DEBUG]   TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  COMMIT
```

Specifically, this shouldn't be happening

```
[DEBUG]   Ink Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "inks".* FROM "inks" WHERE "inks"."pen_id" = '93a45bae-2cf3-48c1-ac00-6b3059dca5ae' LIMIT 1
```

I have tried using `build_association` followed by a `save`, `create_association`, and using an `association=` with an `Association.create` and they all result in an unnecessary Load at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is caused by the fact that the `Pen` is already persisted when the creation of the `Ink` occurs in an `after_create`.

From the [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> - Assigning an object to a `has_one` association automatically saves that object and the object being replaced (if there is one), in order to update their foreign keys - except if the parent object is unsaved (`new_record? == true`).
> - If either of these saves fail (due to one of the objects being invalid), an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` exception is raised and the assignment is cancelled.

So what you are seeing is rails trying to determine if the associated record already exists, so that it can be updated accordingly.

Depending on how your desired outcome you could try `Ink.create(pen_id: self.id, color: 'blue')`; however, I think just moving this to a `before_create` action is probably a better implementation e.g.

```
class Pen < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ink
  before_create :add_ink

  def add_ink
    build_ink(color: "blue")
  end
end
```

According to the [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one)

> :autosave
>
> If true, always save the associated object or destroy it if marked for destruction, when saving the parent object. If false, never save or destroy the associated object. By default, only save the associated object if it’s a new record.

So since this is a `before_create` the `Pen` is a new record and therefore it should save the `Ink` as well, without querying the database.

Comment: Ah hah, very insightful! I ended up having to do ` build_ink` in a `before_create` hook and `ink.pen_id = id; ink.save` in an `after_create` hook. Without that, I was getting a circular call to `Pen.save` when trying to read the ID which is provided by the db.

Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind actually; the save happens implicitly and the ID is updated automatically using your example.

Comment: @jwilm correct. That is why we needed to make sure that `Pen` was not persisted (new record) when performing these actions, so that when the `Pen` is actually saved it saves the `Pen` and the associated `Ink` but does not execute the SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

What if you need some empty pen (without ink)?

What if you need pen with green ink?

I suggest such way

```rb
class CreatePen
  def self.call(params, color: :blue)
    new(params:, color:).call
  end

  def initialize(params:, color:)
    @pen = Pen.new(params)
    @color = color
  end

  def call
    persist_pen
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    pen
  end

  private

  attr_reader :pen, :color

  def persist_pen
    pen.transaction do
      pen.save!

      Ink.create!(color:, pen_id: pen.id) if color.present?

      pen
    end
  end
end
```

In this case you can call it like this:

```
CreatePen.(params) # return pen with blue ink if everything ok
CreatePen.(params, color: :green) # return pen with green ink if everything ok
CreatePen.(params, color: nil) # return empty pen without ink if everything ok
```